# Is it OK to answer vague, unclear questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889357/python-3-guess-the-number-if-statement-in-while-loop/24889773#24889773) recently. The question was pretty vague, not clearly stated, and (in my opinion) didn't show much research effort. However, I knew how to fix what I thought their problem was, so I answered the question anyway (as did others).

I'm wondering if I should answer questions like these at all. On one hand, we are not supposed to encourage questions like these. On the other hand, however well or not well the question was asked, I can still solve the problem. So would the preferred action be to vote to close the question, or to answer it anyway?

Comment: Does "no effort" involve e.g. being an obvious duplicate?

Comment: No, in the case of this question he made a mistake that was a very basic programming error. I guess I can sympathize with them, having been there at one point myself, but it sort of seemed as though he didn't look up his problem before posting. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: It's a toss-up.  You can downvote and close ASAP, you can spend some time encouraging the OP to "flesh out" the question and lead him to the answer, or you can outright answer the perceived question.  I prefer the second option, but unfortunately someone else will usually jump in with the first or third before you've made much progress and your efforts are wasted.

Comment: If your motivation is to help people, sometimes answering a question where a beginner is floundering is satisfying. I will do that, if I feel the OP has put in some effort, or the best of their limited ability. But, for people motivated by rep, they should be aware that they may lose that rep if the question is deleted.

Comment: If the question is totally unclear, and you're having to guess what they might intend, you shouldn't answer it; you should ask to have it clarified first, and VTC if that isn't done. Answering it causes several issues. First, it removes all incentive for the poster to improve it. Second, it has no benefit for future readers (unless they can also guess at the meaning, see that it might resemble their problem, and luck into your answer). Third, it encourages others who see it and think "Well, my question is good enough if this one is", instead of seeing it needs to be improved.

Comment: (continued)  And last, the poster doesn't learn anything, and will continue to post poor, vague questions in the future, because it's been seen that they can still get help even if they do so.

Comment: Be also prepared to lose some rep, even if the question is not deleted: there are people that think that answering a downvoted answer deserve a downvote to, if it's not a really good answer.

Comment: I favour answer-but-educate. Explain that they'll get better answers more reliably and have those answers be more likely to reflect their actual problem if they show their code/versions/explain a little etc. Make a brief / minimal but accurate answer and if appropriate add some "see also"s.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to edit the question to make the intent more clear?   Risky if your interpretation doesn't match the OP's theory about what they are asking, but the result would be a better question and an answer.

Comment: Most people ask for help when they get stuck and have no idea how to resolve the issues by themselves. I suppose giving a hand and helping out is the right thing to do.  At times what may seem to be a basic question for an expert maybe an extremely complex issue for a beginner.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If you understand what the OP is asking, and the question is reasonably answerable, then answer it.

This generally works out better if you are an expert in the subject matter.  Some questions are clear to experts in the language or technology, but unclear to those who might otherwise be able to answer the question had it been written more clearly.

For questions that are evidently unclear (expert knowledge notwithstanding), you should ask for clarification and refrain from answering.  Cast a close vote if it is apparent that the question is not answerable without clarification (i.e. don't guess).

Comment: Also consider editing the question to make it pass muster.

Comment: Wouldn't this be rewarding people who ask bad questions?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, but perhaps if they like it here they'll stick around and learn how to better participate in the future. Having a negative experience isn't how you build a community. I try to make it clear in cases like these that a clearer question would be better.

Comment: @Deduplicator For 2k+ rep users, definitely. If you understand a poorly written, unclear question well enough to answer it, you should also understand it well enough to make it not poorly written or unclear (though I'm definitely guilty of not doing this myself). For users who still have to go through the suggested edit approval queue, they might run into issues getting it approved if people disagree about what's actually being asked.

Comment: I think it's worth adding that sometimes I've seen questions where my own inexperience in the topic makes me think I know exactly what the OP means, when more experienced users are completely missing it, as it's an obvious oversight to them.

Comment: @OllieFord It happens the other way around too: some inexperienced users who may have never faced that sort of problem would not see where the asker comes from at all (in terms of reasoning) and downvote or vote to close, while people with more experience would know straight away what kind of mistake was being made. The problem with this way is that the question is likely to get closed as unclear before the more experienced users can get to it and provide a good answer.

Comment: @Bruno Yes, I can understand that - I was adding to Robert's mention of that, not taking away from it.

Comment: @Anonymous It might reward people who ask bad questions, but just like there's a reason not to encourage bad questions (it doesn't help the site overall), there is a reason to (sometimes) answer and edit bad questions:  it helps the site overall.  If a question is poorly *asked*, but users recognize that the question itself is useful, it can be worthwhile to edit the question and provide a good answer.  Sure, the original asker might not "deserve" such a good response, but the site is improved, and that's a good thing.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor That's a fair point, but it just seems like effort would be better spent on a question where the OP has actually tried to properly ask a question than on one where the OP clearly doesn't care about quality or trying anything.  The low quality questions should be an afterthought at most instead of the one everyone turns to for reputation because they found the simple error that a debugger could also find.

Comment: @Anonymous Agreed.  The typical case is that usually "bad presentation of question" makes for a bad question.  I just wanted to point out that once in a while, it's possible to come across a confusing or poorly written question that actually has some real substance to it.  I wish more of the former were cases of the latter, but I'd even more prefer questions that are better from the start.

Answer (score 2):

I think the tooltips on the Up/Down Vote arrows answer your question.  Good job for taking a stab at providing a useful answer, but feel free to down vote it as well.

New SO user here, and just noticed those tooltips this morning. I was glad for the explanation.

Comment: +1, they clearly say "this question shows research effort, it is useful **and clear**" and "does not show any research effort, it is **unclear** or not useful". If you think that objectively the question is unintelligible, downvote it and don't bother answering and taking leap jumps. Otherwise go ahead and answer it.

Answer (score -3):

I have seen a few questions closed for this reason where I disagreed. Let's say there is a question like:

> How do I debug a program?

It is stupidly generic and shows zero research effort. But I think it can be usefully answered, and the question and the answers will be helpful to future visitors. The answer will not be of the "run this command line" sort, rather it will be a longer guide. But I think these answers fit well on Stack Overflow too.

Of course the more vague a question is, the more likely it has already been answered. Closing it as a duplicate is perfectly appropriate in this case.

Comment: Pet example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167194/why-is-the-spark-task-running-on-a-single-node