# Is it OK to make a clarifying edit to a question if it will invalidate existing answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, edits, etiquette

Every now and again, I'll come across a question that was not clearly explained, so much so that users attempting to answer the question end up *completely misunderstanding the problem*, and end up giving answers that *seem correct*, but in fact *do not* solve the original poster's actual problem.

Examples:

1. [How do you push a Git tag to a branch using a refspec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061481/overwrite-a-branch-with-a-tag-by-force-pushing-it)

   This question [used to have the extremely vague title](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4061481/1) of

   > git push tag -> master

   The problem is actually about force-pushing a specific tag **to overwrite a branch**, [which was correctly answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4061542/456814), despite the vague title. Yet precisely because of the vague title, other users misunderstood the fundamental problem, and just gave answers for pushing tags to a remote repo in general.
2. [How do I properly force a Git push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509543/how-to-properly-force-a-git-push)

   This question is extremely deceptive, because as I pointed out in [my answer to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987631/456814), the original poster's actual problem seems to stem entirely from the fact that he's trying to push to a non-bare Git repo, which isn't something that was clearly explained in [past revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5509543/3). So, basically, the title doesn't match the actual fundamental problem.

### Is it OK to make clarifying edits to these questions that end up invalidating the existing answers that do not address the actual problem?

I've already made [extensive clarifying edits](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4061481/4) to [How do you push a Git tag to a branch using a refspec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061481/overwrite-a-git-branch-with-a-tag-by-force-pushing-it) a few months ago, going so far as to completely rewrite the existing title. However, in doing so, I've basically invalidated some of the existing answers (though, again, those answers do not address the OP's actual problem).

Is that OK? If not, what can be done instead?

With [How do I properly force a Git push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509543/how-to-properly-force-a-git-push), I'd like to edit the title to be

> Why does my non-bare remote repo have uncommitted changes after pushing to it?

to emphasize the fundamental nature of the problem, but if I did that, again, I would end up invalidating some of the existing answers that still claim that the original poster's problem was somehow the way that he was trying to force push.

Is that OK? If not, what can be done instead?

I was thinking that perhaps if someone was going to make such a clarifying edit that invalidates existing answers (that misunderstand the actual problem), then that editor could also add an editor's note to those answers that explains that they're solutions to a different problem:

> **Editor's note:** this answer addresses `<insert problem here>`, which is similar but different to the problem posed in the OP's question.

or are based on earlier revisions of the question:

> **Editor's note:** this answer is based on an earlier revision `<link to revision>` of the OP's question.

What do people think? **I would prefer to edit questions so that they're clearer**, but what do I do in more complicated cases like these?

### Updated thoughts

After giving it some thought, I just wanted to point out that one could make the argument that if the existing answers completely misinterpret the fundamental nature of the problem in the question, **then they're already invalid**, and making a clarifying edit will only highlight their pre-existing invalidity.

Here's another thought: if I would make clarifying edits to a question to improve it when the question *doesn't* have any answers (and I indeed would), then why should it matter if the question *does* have answers? **If people answer a question that isn't clear enough to be correctly answered**, and through clarifying edits it turns out that those users completely misunderstood the fundamental problem, then are they not themselves at least partially to blame for the invalidation of their own answers?

Or am I not thinking about this in the right way?

Along those lines, the answers to [Is it OK to answer vague, unclear questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266426/is-it-ok-to-answer-vague-unclear-questions) may also be relevant.

Comment: If your clarifying edit invalidates existing answers, it is clear that not everyone sees the same question.  Perhaps your edit is invalid.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg so what you're saying is, if I understand the question differently from someone else, then any edits I make to clarify the question according to my understanding of it are inappropriate?

Comment: I didn't say that.  I said that the edit might be inappropriate.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg The edit always might be inappropriate. What's your point?

Comment: My point is that it might be Cupcake who is misinterpreting the intent of the question.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg ok, **for the sake of finding an answer to the Meta question, let's just assume that my interpretation is *correct***. I could be wrong...but let's just assume that I'm actually correct for now.

Comment: Let's not just assume that.  Seems to me that it's a valid objection.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg are you objecting to the idea of editing questions like this in general, or are you objecting to the specific examples that I picked out?

Comment: I have only a cursory knowledge of git, so I am not in a position to judge the particular examples.  It is a general objection.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg would you still stand behind your objections if the person making the clarifying edits had a gold tag badge in the particular topic of the question? What if you were making such edits to [questions in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)?

Comment: If it invalidates existing answers, you should tread with extreme care, gold badge or no.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg fair enough...that's why I'm here to discuss this.

Comment: In my opinion, it's not anyone's job (other than the OP's) to use their Ouija board to discern the OP's intent **and then edit the question to reflect that intent**.  If it's purely a matter of editing an ambiguous title to match the intent (somewhat) more clearly spelled out in the body of the question, that's a different matter.  Any editing by anyone that changes the question in a way as to make existing answers invalid (or perhaps "look stupid") should be clearly flagged in the text as an edit.

Comment: @HotLicks "*Any editing by anyone that changes the question in a way as to make existing answers invalid (or perhaps "look stupid") should be clearly flagged in the text as an edit.*" The thing is, in my second example, some of the existing answers are already invalid ("look silly"), based on how the question is already posed, without having done any radical edits. But I see the point that you're trying to make...though I'm not sure if I agree with it yet.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg your objection seems to equally apply to editing anything, ever. And why say "take care" - that's the context in which the original question was asked. Isn't that like saying, "Don't forget - security is important!" in a question about the best way to encrypt passwords. Sort of a CIO-type contribution :)

Comment: @MatthewLundberg you were right all along. Extreme care must be taken. Gold badges don't mean anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inadvertently Invalidating Answers With a Modest Question Edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311297/inadvertently-invalidating-answers-with-a-modest-question-edit)

Answer (score 23):

I believe this is one of the few cases where invalidating existing answers is permissible, but it depends on the situation as it is a large gray area.

If the question is reasonably clear (but maybe a little vague), but the asker just simply asked the wrong question, then correcting the question and invalidating any of the existing answers would be incorrect.  This would cover things like incorrect terminology, XY Problems, or cases where the OP thinks the problem is with `Foo`, but after some clarifying comments, turns out the problem is with `Bar` (and the original question about `Foo` is a legit question).

But if the question is unclear to the point that there are multiple answers addressing completely different issues (because everyone is interpreting the question differently), then the **answerer** needs to assume the responsibility for guessing at the actual question.

The problem in the 2nd case is that no one except the OP really know what he was trying to ask.

If the OP directly or indirectly clarifies the questions, through editing, comments, or accepting an answer, then it is perfectly acceptable to edit the question to ensure that it is perfectly clear.  It would be good of the editor to ping the other answerers to inform them of the change so they can correct or delete their answers.

But if anyone other than the OP tries to clarify the question based on their own interpretation of the question, and, in the course of doing so, would invalidate existing answers, then I would lean in the direction on not editing in virtually all cases, especially in cases where the editor also provided an answer.  I think there are exceptions to this in cases where there is clear community consensus (via a meta post, chat discussion, or comment discussion under the question) on what the question actually was, or in cases where the question is older and could be an excellent canonical duplicate target for a common problem.

Comment: You know, most likely even the OP didn't know until it was answered or sufficiently clarified.

Comment: @Deduplicator I think it depends on why the question is unclear.  A vague, poorly described question can be clarified by the OP simply by adding the information that should have been asked for in the comments.

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph, what do you mean by if the OP "asked the wrong question"?

Comment: @Cupcake that is supposed to cover situations like incorrect terminology, XY Problems, or cases where the OP thinks the problem is with `Foo`, but after some clarifying comments, turns out the problem is with `Bar` (although the original question about `Foo` is a legit question).

Comment: @psubsee2003 ok, I understand now. "Asking the wrong question" is actually even more complex, because if the question that's asked is a *common* misconception, then the question can remain unedited (provided that it is *clear*), and the best answers to that question will clear up the misconception and explain what the actual problem is. **However**, that's not the case with [the second example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5509543/456814), partly because it's not even a clearly explained question to begin with.

Comment: One of my biggest issues with unclear and poorly formulated questions like these is that they're such a *huge waste of time* to future readers. For both of the examples that I gave in my question, I only stumbled upon those questions *exactly because* I was looking for canonical questions to close duplicates with.

Comment: However, after reading the questions to see if they describe the common problem that a canonical should have, I figure out that the problem is either not the one described in the title (as in the first example), or that the question just doesn't even make any sense, because it's poorly described, like in the second example.

Comment: @Cupcake I think you've stumbled across one of the key problems associated with the current reputation system and how it can be a little incompatible with the goals of SO.  The community has decided that changing questions and invalidating answers is unfair to the answerer.  But the questions can often be Red Herrings to people coming in from Google as they don't necessarily ask what people think they are asking based on the Google search snippet or the title.  I know I've stumbled across these myself when looking for answers.

Comment: @Cupcake I don't think there is a clear answer because editing to clarify will still be based on 1 person's opinion of what was asked.  What's to stop someone who interpreted the question differently from editing your edit to suit their interpretation.

Comment: @psubsee2003 well, in my first example, I think it would be hard to argue that there's a subjective interpretation to the question. The question body itself clearly states what the problem is, it was just the title that was vague and poorly described. But that was just the first example. The second example is definitely much grayer, since in that case, the question body itself is poorly described.

Answer (score 1):

Some questions and answers simply don't go together, but nevertheless get upvoted because they seem to be helping some people.  Even downvoting doesn't help this problem.  The upvotes win, even though the answer is wrong, wrong, wrong.

A clarifying edit, distinct from the original text, can help people who stumble across something like this understand what they're getting - and what they're not getting.

Consider this post from 2009:  [Get full path of a file with FileUpload Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130560/get-full-path-of-a-file-with-fileupload-control/3077008#3077008)

The asker wanted to know how to get the full client path to an uploaded file, which used to be possible with older browsers, but is in fact no longer possible.

The answerer responded with an instruction to "Try Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName);" which will return a path on the server, not the client.  The asker accepted this wrong answer.  Neither is active anymore.  The answer continues to attract misleading upvotes.

The only thing I could think to do was to add a clarifying edit to the answer:

> **Edit:** This answer describes how to get the path to a file on the server. It does not describe how to get the path to a file on the
>   client, which is what the question asked. The answer to that question
>   is "you can't", because modern browser will not tell you the path on
>   the client, for security reasons.

Comment: Yes, [I ended up doing something similar too](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267420/456814). Thank you for your answer!

Comment: In hindsight, what I ended up doing turned out to be a *terrible* idea, so I wouldn't recommend this except in *extremely exceptional* circumstances, such as yours where both the original poster and the answerer have basically stopped using [so], and are no longer available to receive comment feedback and update their posts on their own. But that's just my personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

For these kinds of questions, if the OP has accepted an answer, *which* answer they chose is a clue about what they intended the question to mean. I've edited questions to clarify them in the light of this kind of clue.

Comment: I can see what you mean, but I think this is very dependent on the specific question. For example, in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5509543/456814), the original poster did not find a satisfactory answer to his problem for over a year and a half, which you can see from the timestamps on the various answers. Then [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12610763/1) shows up, because the original poster's question keeps getting a ton of views, because of the title...

Comment: ...so the OP decides to accept the answer anyways, even if it doesn't actually solve the original problem, because *it's useful* to other people. When you look at the timeline of events, it becomes clear as to what everyone's intentions were.

Comment: @Cupcake Of course, what I suggest is not always possible.