# Edits that do not change the meaning of the original post but invalidate posted answers

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, edits

I recently posted an answer to a question. The question was then edited by another user to simplify it, and though it didn't change the original intent of the OP it invalidated my answer (due to different method dispatch used by the new function in the edited OP, compared to the one I answered for).

What is the best way to handle this? On one hand the edit probably improves the question, on the other, the change lead to someone claiming my answer was incorrect and downvoting it, despite it correctly answering the unedited post.

Do I now have to re-edit my answer to keep pace with the edit?

p.s. is this more appropriate for the SE-meta rather than SO-meta?

Comment: Related, though on a tangent: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266946/is-it-ok-to-make-a-clarifying-edit-to-a-question-if-it-will-invalidate-existing

Comment: I'd say if an edit invalidates answers, it either *does* change the meaning of the OP *or* you and the esteemed editor interpreted it quite differently.

Comment: It sounds as though the editor changed the code in the question?  That's almost always inappropriate.

Comment: Was your original answer a good answer to a question worth having on SO? If so, it sounds like the right thing to do is roll back or (better) improve the edit, so it's still an answer people can search for, not to change the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First part, what the editor should have done.

If you change a question, there are broadly two **valid** cases:

1. You clarify it (either as the OP, or using info he left in comments), such that it becomes unambiguously answerable.

   In that case, it is not neccessary to preserve the validity of any answers, though you should not go out of your way to make a guess which answers "the question as intended" ill-fitting.
   Consider adding a comment, at least to those **guesses** which might be salvageable.
2. You are just polishing the question, for example by removing any side-issues which are not the point of the question.

   In that case, **none of the answers are guesses**, though they might have differing quality.
   Make sure none of them look any worse after your edit, if neccessary by editing them too.

---

Now, someone did not follow this guidance:  **Shame on them!**

If you recognize that (irrespective of you owning an answer/the question or not), please take the time to do the follow-on work which was neglected, at least in so far as adding comments notifying later visitors and the posters of the situation (Also consider if doing a slightly different change to the question might make it easier, and the question no worse).

Of course, you have far more latitude in enhancing your own posts than any random editor who decides to spread a bit of editing-love.