# What to do if a user adds tags to question so that a current answer no longer make much sense?

Tags: discussion, answers

I [answered](http://[Dot%20notation%20string%20manipulation%20in%20Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35118430/3100115)) this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35118265/dot-notation-string-manipulation-in-python) which was tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) and now has an open bounty which worth 100 reputations from the owner of the accepted answer(I don't know le pourquoi). The same user also edited the question and re-tagged with [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) and [python-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) also he added a modify version of my answer (see revisions 5 of 6 of his answer) that works in [python-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) without giving a credit and left this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35118265/dot-notation-string-manipulation-in-python/35118303#comment58956916_35118430) on my answer.

> it's not a python-3 question, your first example will throw a TypeError

I think doing so is wrong. What should I to do? flag the comment as not constructive, re-edit the question which can trigger an edit war or update my answer?

Comment: Related: [Edits that do not change the meaning of the original post but invalidate posted answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271400/edits-that-do-not-change-the-meaning-of-the-original-post-but-invalidate-posted).  It's not clear to me why the other answerer added the versioned tags, but maybe there were deleted comments specifying the version.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Which is the reason I just invited him here.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Asserting that a question is about a specific version of a language when it previously wasn't specifying such a thing *is* changing the meaning of that post though.

Comment: @Servy Yes, and if there was a clarifying comment from the author, in that specific case that would have been acceptable.

Comment: @Deduplicator That's correct.

Comment: minitoto added the tags on Feb 2 at 5:59 after the first 3 answers were already added. The OP did not mention any particular version of python.

Comment: Yep.  The [question timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35118265/timeline) confirms this.

Comment: @DavidPostill Whether the change is before or after answers were posted isn't really relevant.  Either the author of the question indicated which version he's using (in a now-deleted comment), in which case it's appropriate, or he didn't, and it's not.  That's really all there is to it.

Comment: The downside to comments being ephemeral.

Comment: the tags were added long time ago, and i just noticed that you answer doesn't work in python 2 the way you posted it, I wanted you to change your answer to work in both versions, no offense was intended

Comment: @servy Surely it **is** relevant if the change invalidates another answer. It smells of "I'll just change the question so my answer works and now your doesn't work any more".

Comment: if OP doesn't provide keyword and just passes number it'll work in both versions.

Comment: @minitoto that's true.  It's just slightly sketchy since you're the one who added the tags that made the other answer less relevant.

Comment: @minitoto The fact that you added the tags several weeks ago doesn't make it okay.  You erroneously added the tags several weeks ago.  It's still erroneous.  You feeling that all answers to all python questions should support version 2 is something that you're allowed to use when evaluating other answers and voting, and you can also intentionally provide answers that will work in older versions if you feel that it makes those answers better, but editing those tags into the question and claiming that the author is using a version *when they have specified no such thing* is **not** appropriate.

Comment: @DavidPostill No, it is not.  If the author made it clear that the question is asking about a specific version of the language, editing the question to reflect that is appropriate, regardless of what answers there might be.  It's adding that information to a question *when the author has specified no such constraint* that is a problem.

Comment: @Servy But the OP never made that clear. It wasn't the OP that changed the question and there was no comment from the OP saying that was his intention.

Comment: @DavidPostill Indeed, and I've stated that the edit is improper for exactly that reason.  The existence of any answers is not relevant; that's my whole point.  The only relevant point is whether or not the author has indicated what version they're using.  If he did, the edit is okay, if he didn't, it's not.  What answers there are, or when they were posted, has nothing to do with it.

Comment: i removed the tags, so OP can be happy know, my comment to his answer makes perfect sense now, since version of Python is not specified, by the way i don't remember exactly why i decided to put version 2.x, the question has been edited several times, and doesn't look the same as it was, i assume it had print before, but not sure, and i don't see the history of edits. So if it's my mistake, my apologies, i made the edit back.

Comment: _"but not sure, and i don't see the history of edits."_ @minitoto You can check the history of edits by clicking the "edited x ago" link on the question. That'll show you all the revisions to whatever quesiton you're looking at.

Comment: thanks Kendra, didn't know it, thought i just didn't yet have that privilege

Comment: Just checked the history, you are right OP didn't mention python 2, i don't recall why exactly i added python2 tag, but my bad anyway. I corrected all back

Comment: @minitoto Just curious, why did you add a bounty to that question?

Comment: @DanielNugent to honor other answers, and probably get some + to my answer

Comment: @minitoto Ahh, nice! Makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The edit to the question to specify a specific version when the author has provided no indication that they are using any specific version isn't appropriate.  You could consider commenting to that editor to explain this, to try to avoid an edit war, but given that there really doesn't seem to be any indication that the author has a specific version (unless there's a now-deleted comment to that effect) you could probably edit out those tags as well.

As far as his comment, no, you don't flag comments because you think they're wrong.   If you want to reply, and explain that the author hasn't indicated in any way what version of Python they're using, you're certainly welcome to, but the comment is in no way unconstructive, regardless of its factual accuracy.

Your assertion that his answer is plagiarizing yours doesn't really seem merited.  The fact that two single line of code solutions are similar (in that they both use the same one method to solve the problem) isn't a sign that someone is "stealing" your content; the content is just too simple for the answers to *not* have such similarities.  And it's not even like they're exactly the same (far from it).  Posting some code that's similar to another answer but that functions differently, and is supported in different versions, is entirely appropriate.

If you want to update your answer to work with older version you certainly *can*, there's nothing *wrong* with it.  Given that there's already another answer that already has that information though, I don't know if I'd see the point personally.

Comment: Nice answer @Servy

Comment: @user3100115 to be honest there is nothing to do with plagiarizing, it's not like you discovered the America using rsplit, i didn't add it initially because it was in your answer, when i started the bounty i noticed that rsplit works differently in python 3, so i added version which works in both.