# Approve or reject 'good' edits that only make sense if Q and A's are both changed?

Tags: discussion, edits

This is a fairly general issue, but I offer a simple example to illustrate.

I recently came across a suggested edit for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37746713/how-to-create-a-vector-with-factor-level-frequency/37746778#37746778) post.  The original question used the name `F` for a variable.  In`R-language`, `F` is also shorthand for `FALSE`, making it bad practice to use this as a variable name (because things like `if (x==F)` can have unexpected consequences. So, accordingly, I approved the change which changed the variable name to something more sensible.

However, several answers to this question also use the variable name `F` as per OP. Unless `F` is changed to a more sensible name in all the answers and in the question simultaneously, making this edit could break some answers.

So, here is the question.  Given that I cannot ensure that the suggested edit will be approved on all of the Q and A's (different reviewers may see each edit and take a different response), is it better to reject an edit that only works when all Q&A's are changed?  Even if this means leaving the post in its original but worse form?

**Edit**
This question is related to ["edits that do not change the meaning of the original post but invalidate posted answers"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271400/edits-that-do-not-change-the-meaning-of-the-original-post-but-invalidate-posted).

However, I think that there is an important difference, in that the user making the edit made their best attempt to change the question and the answers so that they would all be improved in the same way and none of them would suffer.  But the problem is that not having enough rep to make these edits without it passing through review, they are unable to guarantee that either *all* or *none* of the edits will be approved.  Either of these cases would be ok, but the worst case is that some of the edits are approved and others are not.

Given this uncertainty, the edits should probably never have been made.  But now that they are, how should a reviewer respond when it is also outside their control whether all edits get approved/rejected consistently?

The accepted answer answer to ["edits that do not change the meaning of the original post but invalidate posted answers"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271400/edits-that-do-not-change-the-meaning-of-the-original-post-but-invalidate-posted) gives the following advice:

> If you change a question, there are broadly two **valid** cases:
>
> 1. ...
> 2. You are just polishing the question, for example by removing any side-issues which are not the point of the question.
>
>    In that case... make sure none of the answers look any worse after
>      your edit, if necessary by editing them too.

which accurately describes what the editor did in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edits that do not change the meaning of the original post but invalidate posted answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271400/edits-that-do-not-change-the-meaning-of-the-original-post-but-invalidate-posted)

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266946/is-it-ok-to-make-a-clarifying-edit-to-a-question-if-it-will-invalidate-existing

Comment: @sphanley. Thanks for these links.  They are definitely related and useful. But see edit explaining why I think this question is different.

Answer (score -2):

Really this is a change that nobody but the OP should make to the question.  The fact that something like thus could cause problems is *exactly why you shouldn't change it* as it may well be an underlying cause if the problem that sparked the question.  If it's not, and the OP confirms that by editing it (perhaps in response to a comment), then it would be fine to edit (or approve edits to) answers to be in line with the question.