# Dealing with questions that are edited after my answer has been accepted

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I recently answered a question posted to Stack Overflow. The answer was accepted.

While my answer currently on the question solved the original post, the OP has edited the question/title to a completely new scenario.

While my answer was on-topic to begin with, it's now a sore thumb with the recent edit changing everything.

Shall I leave my answer there? (I have mentioned to the user the process of follow-up questions) which could attract downvotes in the future due to the original solution being made irrelevant.

Comment: @hovercraftfullofeels whilst the question being somewhat answered multiple times across SO, I decided to give an answer. I don't fully care for the reputation gained from an accepted question nor the up votes,  the topic at hand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447071/php-registration-form-not-able-to-store-data-in-the-mysql-database-and-giving-er/33447115#33447115  if you check the revisions it'll be clear

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: Knowing how to invest your free time is getting to be pretty important at SO.  There's a flood of this kind of cr*p, a "you forgot a semi-colon" answer just isn't very useful to anybody.  There's a dedicated close reason for that, best to use it.

Comment: @Hans. I'm new to this so: If the answer is a typo in the code, why is mentioning that not enough / not useful?

Comment: It is okay to "mention" it, a comment gets the job done.  It is not okay to flood the internet and search engine queries with "you got a typo" answers.  The kind that has all the keywords that a search engine indexes but almost never produces a useful search result.  I recognize your name from the MSDN forums, not close to the SO model.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would roll-back the question to a state that matches the current accepted answer, no remorse.

In the edit comment I would explicitly state that changing the gist of the question AFTER there are answers posted is counter-productive and a waste of the answerers time.

If you feel to it you can leave a comment to link the OP to a deeper explanation of the frowned upon behavior, like:

- [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)
- [What is a help vampire?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire)

If the OP rolls-back again the post will be auto-flagged for a moderator.

The only case where this can be allowed is if the question wasn't  clear enough in describing the **actual** problem leading to answers that solve symptoms instead of the root cause. [This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266946/is-it-ok-to-make-a-clarifying-edit-to-a-question-if-it-will-invalidate-existing) from [Cupcake](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/456814/cupcake) and its answers address that case.

Comment: In order to provide a custom message to the auto-summary of a rollback revision, one would have to go to the revision history, click on the *edit* link of the revision you want to revert to, write a good summary why reverting was necessary and submit the "edit". The summary will be "Rollback to Revision <x> - <your msg>". This probably works for all users.

Comment: @rene what if the answer was not accepted but the question is edited?

Comment: @Anish웃 I don't think that makes much difference unless the question was unclear and due to the answer the OP sees what needs to be added. Assuming the question is still similar, not completely changed.

Answer (score 19):

I'd comment to the user and ask them not to do this and for them to revert the question back to its original state so as not to invalidate your answer. I'd let them know

1. that questions and answers are not for their benefit only, but are also (and mainly) for the benefit of future visitors with similar problems, and
2. that if they have a new unique problem, they should ask a completely new question, without defacing the original question.

If they refuse or don't respond, perhaps this is time to flag a moderator.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot give this an accepted tick for another few minutes. Can definitely use this as a reminder if similar things happen in the future. Thank you

Comment: @DarylGill: you're welcome, but before accepting anything, let's wait and see if any better answers come along. Meta answers usually come slower than the SO site.