# What to do with questions that are changed after being answered; but that have an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, help-vampire

Sometimes a user will edit their question after answers have been posted, making already existing answers obsolete. The common and accepted course of action is to rollback the question to its original state, as expressed in posts like these:

1. [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) (from MSE) gives some good suggestions for a one-on-one scenario, i.e. how *you* answer the question.
2. [Dealing with questions that are edited after my answer has been accepted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309237/dealing-with-questions-that-are-edited-after-my-answer-has-been-accepted) (MSO) deals with what to do with with a question that's changed after an answer has been given.

Does this advice still apply in case the edited question has an accepted answer, and the accepted answer matches to the edited version and some other answers match the original version?

Should it still be rolled back, or some other course of action is advisable?

Comment: Neither of these options. Rollback the edits to your question to the point where the original answers were relevant.

Comment: @yivi, What if there's an accepted answer? Surely then you end up with nonsense?

Comment: If you the questioner changes the question **after** it was answered, rolling back is the way to go, IMO. Acceptance is not terribly important.

Comment: @yivi, OK, and just live with the fact the accepted answer will not match the question? I can see this confusing everyone..

Comment: The OP is free to accept whatever they want, not much we can do about it. But changing the meaning of the question after it was answered is both confusing for future visitors and in bad taste regarding the users that already put in effort answering.

Comment: @yivi, I can agree with this. Bad for the Q&accepted-A, but better for the long run. I want to avoid arguments with the chameleon-answerers, so it would be good to get a consensus - if you're happy to write up this answer.

Comment: @yivi, done. Though I see nothing wrong.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a simple issue. There are multiples considerations, ie. would you rollback an edit that makes an off topic question and on topic one because there were answers that answer that off topic question? Obviously no, it would be counter productive.

With that in mind the real question you have to ask is:

Did the edit made the question better?

That's what you have consider. If the OP (or whoever) felt that there were some aspect of their question that were unclear or ambiguous and the edit corrected that, we want those kind of edits. The same reason as I started apply if the question should/is closed by any of the close reasons and the asker fixed that issues.

We want the questions to be the best possible, and if we have to pay the cost of a couple answers that should have been withhold until the problems were fixed, so be it.

Comment: I don't disagree with your answer. However, my definition of "chameleon question" is simply one that *changes* [both original and updated versions are acceptable]. You're right, we should never roll back a question to make it *worse*. The way I see it, there are 2 options in this case: roll back & live with the Q&Accepted-A being inconsistent; or delete your answer to the original question since it's no longer relevant.

Comment: @jpp what about the case where OP left out a critical detail for their context that changed the question? ie. can't do X due Y reasons.

Comment: That improves the question, sure. I'm talking about when a question extends or changes without a "quality change" - check out help-vampires. Happens mostly with new users.