# How to improve an old, bad question when editing may invalidate exising answers?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592903/how-to-not-evaluate-a-variable-as-soon-as-its-defined) that I asked last year is still receiving downvotes to this day.

I've gotten better at programming, and now I realize how stupid the example code in the question is.

I edited the question twice to clarify it with brand-new example code, but they were [rolled back](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41592903/revisions) because they were too drastic.

How do I improve my old question? Asking a new question seems like a bad idea because it's a duplicate.

Comment: You'll get some more, featuring it on meta is a quick way to get used to it.

Comment: The question is [locked](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41592903/revisions) and thus cannot be voted on anymore. Downvotes averted?

Comment: @Justastudent My problem is not about downvotes but about editing to improve a question that already has answers.

Comment: @sag if the question already has answers, editing is fine as long as you do not change the intent of the question and make the answers obsolete in the process. So it very well may be that a question is beyond fixing. You can always submit a [disassociation request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request), if the question lock is not enough.

Comment: @yivi The lock may be temporary.

Comment: @Dukeling That's why I said they could submit a disassociation request.

Comment: I think its a reasonable question. Sure the premise is misguided but the question itself is clear, on-topic, and obviously answerable. I really don't see what the problem is. As for the edits, yeah that would be an entirely different question, and definitely not as clear or concise of a question as the original.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Generally, if a question was asked which presented an intelligible problem, we don't want the question to be edited in a way that invalidates answers already given.

The degree to which it is enforced depends on context. Editing a question without answers won't invalidate anything, so no problem. If a question is *still relatively new*, and the answers the question is getting indicates that the question needs clarification, and the OP edits it in a way may invalidate answers, my experience is that such edits to a question are usually tolerated.

However, the more settled the question has become, the less likely it is to be okay to edit the question such that existing answers become invalid. Here are some salient points of the history of your question:

1. You posted it in Jan 11th 2017.
2. You posted a bounty on Jan 17th 2017.
3. You got an answer from me on Jan 18th 2017 explaining that we use functions for the problem you described.
4. I cannot readily find a precise date for this, but at some point, *you accepted my answer*, and I got the bounty you had offered. (It definitely was accepted, and I definitely got a reputation notification recently when it was unaccepted. I can readily find the unacceptance event at 2018-07-13 05:09Z in my reputation history.)
5. Then, roughly a year and a half after you asked your original question and accepted my answer, you decided to edit it in a way that invalidates my answer. This part (in [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41592903/9)) is not merely a *clarification* but a *new requirement*:

   > You may think, "Why not just use a function?" Look, I dowant to store an EXPRESSION. It should be possible to add expressions together and compare expressions.

   You also unaccepted my answer but that's entirely your prerogative.

As I see it, your question has reached a long time ago the degree at which a question is so settled that radical edits become problematic. If you want to correct typos, syntax errors, or just clarify the language, fine. But adding new requirements is not okay.

This being said, it looks like the problem you were trying to solve is your association with a heavily downvoted question. You may ask moderators for being dissociated from your question. I don't know the details of how that works though, other than you need to ask a moderator.

Comment: "we don't want the question to be edited in a way that invalidates answers already given" [citation needed], because we do https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341987/792066

Answer (score 9):

> How do I improve my old question?

By improving the question, rather than changing it into a different question.  Changing the way in which the question is asked, so that it's clearer, more concise, less ambiguous, better formatted, etc. are all ways of improving a question.  Your edits weren't improving it, they were fundamentally changing what the question was asking for.

> Asking a new question seems like a bad idea because it's a duplicate.

Your new question may be a duplicate of some other question, but it's not a duplicate of the question you're asking about.  Your existing question is asking how to defer execution of some code until a later point in time.  Your edited question is asking how to do static analysis of JavaScript code in order to determine if two arbitrary expressions are equivalent.  The first question is complete enough, insofar as it contains enough information to be answered.  People can, and have, provided you with solutions that allow you to defer execution of a given JavaScript expression until exactly the moment you desire.

Your edited question is not only very different, but it's woefully incomplete.  You list off a handful of examples of expressions that you want to consider "equivalent", but, from my reading, there's no where near enough information to actually determine what *you* think equivalent expressions are, given that you've compared very different expressions (as far as what the compiler will interpret them) and said you want them to be equivalent.  Are you just asking how to determine if the results of evaluating the expressions are equivalent?  Because if so, even *that* isn't borne out by your examples.  Do you want to know if the results of evaluating the expressions can be implicitly converted to each other?  If so, then lots of *wildly* different expressions will be "equal".  Do you want to know the previous question, but with the added condition that the results be the same regardless of the state of the environment it's executed in?

So all around very unclear.  And also, depending on which one of those many possible interpretations you're asking for, almost certainly too broad (the only one that wouldn't be is most likely evaluating the results of the expressions in the same environment and comparing them for either equality or whether one is convertible to the other, which frankly would make a bad question because "how do I execute these two expressions and compare their results for equality" is... a bad question.  You shouldn't need to ask on SO to figure out how to do that one.

Comment: "rather than changing it into a different question" how exactly is the question changed?

Comment: @Braiam I spent basically the entire post explaining how the two questions are asking for different things, so I don't understand the question?  Here I was thinking that I spent *too much* time explaining how what the questions are asking for are different.  Are you being sarcastic?

Comment: @Braiam Do you really think that trying to defer execution of an expression is exactly the same problem as performing static analysis of two expressions to determine if their are somehow equivalent, and that answers to one will necessarily answer the other?  Or do you think that those are not accurate summaries of the two revisions of the question, if so, which one, and why?

Comment: No, you spent your entire post saying that you cannot change the question, you didn't explain **how it was changed such that main issue is different**. You say "woefully incomplete", when the OP added more information. So, it should be incomplete, with less information. That's not changing the question, he's clarifying, just that according you *the amount of clarification isn't enough*. That's not changing the question, is improving the question.

Comment: @Braiam I spent the first paragraph saying that you can't change the question to a different question.  The whole rest of the post is explaining how the questions are fundamentally different questions.  No, you can't just say that adding information can never make a question less clear.  The edits *aren't* just adding information, they have also removed the entirety of the original question, replacing it with a new, different, question.  One could make a clear question unclear by adding to it, but that's off topic here as it didn't happen.

Comment: You'd *stated* that you think the question was clarified, and not changed to a different question.  What's your basis for that assertion?  How are the two revisions asking the same question?  I've summarized what the two revisions are asking for.  How are those summaries wrong, or how are they actually fundamentally the same question?  I spent the three paragraphs above explaining how the questions are *fundamentally* different.  You need to do more than just *state*, without evidence, that they're the same.

Comment: "The whole rest of the post is explaining how the questions are fundamentally different questions" no, the rest of the post is explaining how you believe that the post isn't satisfying to you, not a different question. Still, you haven't explained how it changed. Lets give you a hint: reduce both questions to a single sentence, does it change?

Comment: @Braiam I did precisely that [right here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371160/how-to-improve-an-old-bad-question-when-editing-may-invalidate-exising-answers/371180?noredirect=1#comment610829_371180).  I *specifically* asked you how those two summaries were either the same question, or not applicable to the two revisions.  You've...asked me to provide the summaries *again*, despite them already been put forth *multiple* times.  Are you just trolling?  Or did you just not take the time to read either the entirety of the post or any of my comments?

Comment: "How do I make the variable stay as the unevaluated 2 + 2 expression and not change to 4?" == "How do I make the variable stay as 2 + 2 and not change to 4 until the program gets to the line where I command for a to be evaluated?" Aren't both the same question? Where it says to do static analysis?

Comment: @Braiam It's the whole second half of the edited question where they demonstrate two different ways of having an expression that is not evaluated, but say that those are not variable options because they do not provide any way to determine if two expressions are "equivalent".  It is therefore stating, as a requirement for the question, that these stored expressions need a way to be evaluated for "equivalence".  The original question only ever stated that the unevaluated expressions needed a way to be evaluated later.

Answer (score 4):

While the subject is probably trivial for most users here, and especially probably most downvoters, I think the question is fine as it is.

It's rather short, clear, and with sort of pseudocode examples.

It is probably a general notion that is useful to many beginners.

Some could find it too broad, but I think the problem is explicitly simple and is precisely answerable as it is (which makes it *de facto* not too broad).

The title is fine too for me. I can remember a time when I couldn't name the concept, this title matches what I could have typed in google to search by myself at the time.

The fact that some answers have lots of upvotes is, to me, the proof that the question is useful.

Some users landed here and find value in answer and upvoted it. That means that the question is worthy of staying.

If we could find a (canonical) duplicate, then, of course, it should be closed in favor of it. In the opposite case, I think this question could be some target duplicate of other beginner's questions of the same vein. I occasionally read some, and I unfortunately don't have an example right now.

TL;DR

I'm sorry for your downvotes, I personally don't understand them either.

Don't edit it (except for minor edition).

If you find some more recent questions on the same subject without answer, flag them for duplicate to yours. Maybe at some point you'll get more positive votes.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I improve my old question? Asking a new question seems like a bad idea because it's a duplicate.

Replacing the question with a different one, especially after it got answered, is against the generally accepted rules here.

When I read you old question as it was originally asked, I have an impression that you are not quite able to explain the problem that you are trying to solve.

When I read that question after you tried to improve it (and before the edit was rolled back), I have an impression that your understanding of the problem has evolved enough that editing that question turned it into a different one. People here confirm it because they think that your edit has invalidated the answers. And I think that if you post your edited version as a new question it will not be a duplicate. It seems that you are still having the same problem, but nothing prevents asking several questions about a single problem, provided that the problem is deep enough.

However, I still think that you are unable to explain the problem that you are trying to solve. Your edited version mentioned the difference between expressions and strings, but you have to be precise about which kind of expressions are you talking about. Are these just generic math expressions of some kind, or are these expressions the same expressions which are allowed in javascript language, and if so, are there any restrictions or do you want to support javascript language in full? The answers will be wildly different depending on which kind of expression language do you want.

Comment: "is against the generally accepted rules here"[citation needed] https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341987/792066

Comment: @Braiam [dealing-with-questions-that-are-edited-after-my-answer-has-been-accepted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309237/dealing-with-questions-that-are-edited-after-my-answer-has-been-accepted/309245#309245), see also [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=chameleon+questions)

Comment: @Braiam changing an off-topic question into an on-topic version of the same question is fine even if it invalidates existing answers because those answers were off-topic. This question is not and has never been off-topic.

Comment: @artem an oversimplification of "expression" as used in the JavaScript world is anything that can go on the right hand side of an assignment expression (including an assignment expression). That part is not unclear.

Comment: @TinyGiant that's debatable because the edited question asks about "whether 2 math expressions are the same expression", if you allow anything that's allowed in javascript including variables and functions, the problem becomes undecidable I think, at least if you define "same" as "always producing the same result"

Comment: @artem the answer is "put it in a function" which is clear and obvious. The new question is irrelevant because it is a different question entirely. The problem is that the user is associated with a question that is heavily downvoted even though there is nothing wrong with the question. They are attempting to change the question into a different question in hope that they might stop the downvotes, but this is simply not how things are done here. The fact that the question is being downvoted at all is shameful because there is really nothing wrong with the original question as it is.

Comment: @TinyGiant "I have an impression that you are not quite able to explain the problem that you are trying to solve." unclear question to a clear one. Basically, artem itself reckons that the original question wasn't very clear. OP edited to clarify. Such thing **should never be disallowed**.

Comment: @Braiam but it's not unclear. The question asked is quite clear. It is based on a misguided premise, but the problem itself is clear, answerable, and on-topic as it is. The problem with the question is not the clarity, scope, or quality of the question. The problem with the question is that it is heavily downvoted seemingly because of the misguided premise, which seems like a bad reason to downvote a question.

Comment: That's exactly how I view it. The original question was clear, but it failed to convey the problem that OP has. When OP tried to edit the question to better explain the same problem, it became a different question.

Comment: "The original question was clear, but it **failed to convey the problem that OP has**" Then it wasn't clear. For something to be clear it *has to convey the same information to all parties*.

Comment: @Braiam it was a question that described a problem, it could be understood and answered. Just the problem, as perceived by people who answered it, was not the one the author intended it to be. Taken in isolation, it looked like a clear, somewhat reasonable, beginner-level question. We can not guess the intent, the text in question is the only thing what we have. My point is, if the question is clear, but clearly describes the wrong problem, leave it as it is and ask a different one.

Comment: If what you understand, isn't what I'm trying to convey, then there's a problem of communication. That problem is called lack of clarity due different levels of information. OP added more information **to clarify** what exactly was his issue. You all understood another thing due the lack of that information. Is not the same that I tell you that "I'm hurt" when you aren't seeing me, that if you where in front of me and see me with a gaping wound. You could presume that "my feelings are hurt", but it isn't what I'm trying to convey. If I clarify "I have a gaping wound that hurts" is different.

Answer (score 1):

As far as questions from beginner programmers go, *that's actually not bad at all*. It's pretty clear evidence of you slamming up against the constructs of the language and looking for a way to live in that territory. It's one of those questions someone asks when they're in the process of transitioning *up* a skill level.

I've seen *far* more confused outbursts from people on the cusp of really understanding mutual exclusion and atomic locks.

There's really no way you can go back and erase history, because everyone begins everything at some point, no? Personally, I keep stuff like that around to remind myself of where I came from. But, *you do have a right to be forgotten*, and our CC license allows for you to do that selectively.

If a work has evolved to something that you no longer wish to be associated with (and let's say collecting a ton of down votes is evolving negatively), you can simply [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and request that the post be disassociated from your account. It'll then be attributed to an anonymous 'shadow' user and vanish from your profile, and you'll get any rep back that you lost (as well as lose any that you gained, e.g. the upvote I just gave you).

If it's a constant annoyance, just get rid of it. If it reminds you that you didn't always know everything a few times a year - you know, it's probably worth keeping.

Comment: Tim, while the downvotes is something that the OP is bothered about, what they really want is to actually improve the question into something they feel satisfied with, given their current knownledge. Our community is actually blocking such attempts, which is absurd.

Comment: @Braiam No, they're trying to remove the question entirely and replace it with an entirely different question.  They're being told that if they have a new question they should *ask a new question*, rather than editing their new question into an old question.  They are of course also welcome to improve their existing question.  But improving a question means asking *the same question* more effectively, not replacing it with a different question.