# Inadvertently Invalidating Answers With a Modest Question Edit

Tags: discussion, edits

There is this Q which was brought up on Meta which I've been personally overseeing and trying to nurture/protect by placing a bounty on it:

[In C++, should I bother to cache variables, or let the compiler do the optimization? (Aliasing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898371/in-c-should-i-bother-to-cache-variables-or-let-the-compiler-do-the-optimizat)

... though it hardly needed my help -- it already had 55 up-votes within a couple day's time before I placed the bounty (but also 3 close votes).

It's one I see as a potential pearl since I read a paper on this very subject (the difficulties that aliasing present on compiler optimizations). Also I tend to spend all day looking at basic troubleshooting homework-style questions -- these kinds of questions are so rare and precious when I see them.

Yet, while it already has some pearly answers, the question is quite flawed.

I ended up making the smallest edit to it to try to save it and protect it. I changed: `Is it worth optimizing it [...]?` to merely `Could there be a case where this could yield more efficient results [...]?`.

In the process, even with such a delicate edit, I already invalidated one answer: Roddy's. He gave the wise answer: `"Let the compiler worry about it."` According to him, he was already receiving up and down votes and was already heading down towards zero before I made the edit. But I definitely made his answer worse with that edit.

What should I do in that case? I feel guilty, and many apologies to Roddy for the edit!

Worse, this Q has one last glaring flaw in it which I didn't edit:
`What would you consider to be "better" code?`

I'm tempted to edit that out also to try to make this question really worthy of the archives. But that would also screw some of those people who provided general wisdom answers over even more. I'm torn about what to do.

Comment: Oh, I'm glad I read the whole question, I was misguided by the title

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton Oh phew, thanks for pointing that out! I changed it a bit, hopefully people don't confuse my intentions.

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton Could you tell me how you initially interpreted it? English is not my first language, and I am always so afraid of misleading people by using the wrong word.

Comment: @ike You're a pearl diver, be sure enough oxygen is supplied ;-) ...

Comment: *Screwing People Who Answer With an Edit* I read it as how to deal with people who answer questions with edits lol, but oh well English isn't my first language either, and maybe that's why I misinterpreted it.

Comment: I'm a native speaker/reader, and I had to reparse the title -- it's a bit of a garden path.  I've edited to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Much appreciated! Ah -- I didn't realize that "Answerers" was a word -- that makes it a lot easier!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matter is peculiar and takes care when dissecting. Here's the research:

1. This isn't a "smallest edit" because with it, you **shifted the question's focus.**
2. You did this because *in the original form, the question was off-topic* ("primarily opinion-based" in this case) *and thus would probably be closed.* And the close would be completely valid.
3. As per 2),

   - the answers that answer the original question *as it was formulated* (asking for opinion) *are also invalid* (provide an opinion rather than facts). Consequently, **these deserve to be invalidated** since they were invalid in the first place.
   - answers that *ignore the invalid focus and rather "automatically adjust the question"* to be valid and answer that instead will either

     - **not be invalidated** and are thus of no concern, or
     - be invalidated *because its author "fixed" the question differently than you.* But **it's their, rather than your, fault.** Because **they didn't bother to fix the question proper** and preferred to make a wild guess instead.
4. As per 3), **your change does not break anything that wasn't already broken,** so **you have nothing to feel guilty about.** But, as per 1), *this is actually a major change,* so **you should leave a comment clearly stating the fact of your edit, its gist and the solid grounds for it** that empower you to do a change that's otherwise prohibited.

   - if your change was potentially controversial i.e. *if there was no single obvious "fix",* you should have *informed the OP instead* and leave it up to them to make up their mind on which fix they prefer (e.g.: "Gonna be closed as "primarily opinion-based" as this is now. Please fix to ask for facts rather than opinions, e.g. <examples of possible ways>"). But, if you ask me, the fix *is* obvious here, so this isn't the case.

Comment: I ended up consulting with the OP for that one but it definitely does shift the question's focus. I found Roddy was fairly open-minded to the change and agreed that it improved the question (but still feel guilty if it contributed to any of his down-votes). What I ended up doing as a form of damage control was editing Roddy's answer to simply cite the original wording of the question. It seems that since I did that, his answer rating has gone back up into the positives.

Comment: @Ike Well, yes, leaving a comment under the affected answer, too (or elsewhere and prefix it with `@<affected_user>`), looks like a good idea - the user gets a notification and thus has a chance to react to the change.