# Ambiguous question - should I delete or edit my answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question

The question [Lifetime Extension of a initializer_list return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656076/lifetime-extension-of-a-initializer-list-return) seemingly is a double XY question. The question title and some of the question body is talking about a problem that OP doesn't actually want to solve (and is an invalid problem, because the code shouldn't compile in conforming compilers.) And the problem OP actually wants to solve is ambiguous.

It could be interpreted two ways:

- OP listed two solutions they've thought of that are not ideal. They want an alternative solution that requires mind-reading. [One answer did that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37657394/6292850) This is how I initially interpreted the question, until:
- [I gained insight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37657446/6292850) from the way the code was written that maybe they were actually trying to solve a different problem. That is until OP wrote a comment that no, [the mind-reading solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656076/lifetime-extension-of-a-initializer-list-return#comment62794244_37657446) was what they were after.

In other words, my answer is invalid because it answers the double XY problem and not the hidden question. On one hand, I think my answer is still useful. On the other hand, it's confusing to others who may think that I'm not addressing the problem at all.

So why don't I edit my answer? Because the other answer is good enough as it is and I don't want to duplicate information, or list more broad solutions. What should I do here?

Comment: Have you considered that maybe you just misread the question? Thinking about it logically: Before edit, your answer is invalid because it wasn't what OP was asking. After clarifying edit, your answer is definitely invalid. So logically, the only thing to do is to remove your answer since it's 100% incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [Is it OK to make a clarifying edit to a question if it will invalidate existing answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266946/6412786) contains the answer you're looking for.

> But if the question is unclear to the point that there are multiple answers addressing completely different issues (because everyone is interpreting the question differently), then the **answerer** needs to assume the responsibility for guessing at the actual question.

It seems that everybody but **you** knew what the OP was asking about. Therefore the problem lies with you. If you see a problem that's unclear, post a comment under the question. Don't guess at what the actual problem is and post an answer just to gain free reputation points. It creates noise.

Since it's clear that your answer does not actually address the problem at all, an edit will not help. Just delete it.