# Unsure how to handle typo question with vague title

Tags: support, questions

**[Unexpected Behavior of "if" statement when using "=" to test for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27573002/1026459)**

That is the question. The problem encountered by the OP was that they used `if( a = b )` as opposed to `if( a == b)`.

The situation was properly outlined in the body of the question. However, this should have been immediately obvious, and changing one `=` doesn't seem to me to be exactly of value.

Recently, it was pointed out in the post **[Did Google recently update algorithms in a way that's bad for Stack Overflow questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280328/1026459)** that Stack Overflow's SEO ranking dropped due to an update of google's algorithm (although the exact metric is hard to pin point).

I think questions like the one linked at the top are contributing to this. It has absolutely no value from a search perspective. "Javascript working only once" could mean almost anything.

Editing the title would need to reflect some aspect of the post, but the post is literally about the difference in using `=` versus `==`, although the OP doesn't know that.

Not only is this question unlikely to actually help any future visitors, it seems troubling for it to remain. I have downvoted and voted to close, but since the title is so vague it wont get enough attention to be removed.

It also seems troubling to reward questions like these with answers, it received 3. I know that recently the outlook has been

> If you understand what the OP is asking, and the question is reasonably answerable, then answer it. [Robert Harvey♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266427/1026459)

So, while I am sure this will bring attention to the post in question, I am more curious what to do in the future.

- How can these types of posts be disposed of more quickly? Posting on meta for every one both clutters meta and lacks efficiency.
- I know that it has low traffic, should I edit it into a form which reflects what it really is (even though that will cast the OP as perhaps asking an obvious question)?
- Do I just ignore these, downvote and move on as the motto is? Because this seems to leave a lot of cruft around (remember the close vote review queue?)

Comment: @Compass - Yes, I cast that close vote. It is the only one on the question at the moment. Since it is destined to be a low traffic post, had this not been brought to light it probably would have remained the only vote for quite some time.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're asking. You have 3 questions in bullet points. I addressed the last one since that was the easiest. Perhaps you should reframe a "main" question so it will be easier to discuss.

Comment: @Compass - Sorry you misunderstood. Perhaps you should read the entire post instead of the last line :) These are 3 aspects of the problem being addressed. Vague titled, off topic questions with low traffic seem to remain longer than they should. Having answers only legitimizes them. The 3 bullets at the bottom highlight possible avenues of dealing with these types of questions, but I would like some clarity on what other options users can take to ensure these types of questions are not cluttering the site.

Comment: I have a Turing machine mentality and questions pop off the stack after I read more than one TT_TT. Anyways, we should strive to clean these up whenever possible, through built in flagging. We're wasting people's time going "Hey, this question really sucks, we should delete it immediately!" Rather than letting it die from old age or lack of use.

Comment: @Compass - Yes, flagging is an option I considered. But beyond simply casting a closure vote, I am curious if it would be pertinent to either flag this as low quality or even with a custom message for a Mod.

Comment: I would assume such a post would naturally flow through the First Post queue, though, since it is a first post.

Comment: @Compass - It was reviewed as no action needed: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/6534888 (not surprised, but still a little disappointed).

Comment: Ugh... well, we can flag this and downvote at the very least.

Comment: I have downvoted it and voted to close, and edited the title to be Unexpected Behavior of "if" statement when using "=" to test for equality

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the reason why I proposed this feature request:

[Do we really need to keep closed typo questions with accepted/upvoted answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273266/do-we-really-need-to-keep-closed-typo-questions-with-accepted-upvoted-answers).

Flagging for moderator attention or Coming to meta for each and every one of them is not practical. Like Lightness Races in Orbit rightly said - Questions like this adds nothing to the Q&A repository.

**They should be taken care by the [roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion)**.

Answer (score 5):

I consider it unlikely that the Google bot would be tuned to recognize typo questions.  Or for that matter pay any attention to whether a question is closed.  If Google customizes their bot for specific web sites then that's a very well-kept secret.

If there's any accuracy in the SEO wags' opinion, the Penguin updates were tuned to recognize link traps.  And SO has a *lot* of them, adding them at a high rate as well.  Questions closed as duplicate, linking to a stale existing page that has not been updated in ages.  SE always liked that feature, good SEO juice and keeps the complaints down.  Maybe it isn't anymore.

Let's not kid ourselves, SO has *not* been good at adding good fresh content lately.  The site numbers have been poor with an inflection point in November of last year when growth disappeared.  For a site that adds a *quarter of a million* new web pages a month, no growth is equivalent to death.  Not much new or interesting to see here anymore, you'd expect a company that indexes the world to recognize this.

Getting this fixed must start at getting the rate at which junk gets added slowed down to a rate at which it can possibly be removed.  We lost that battle 2 years ago.  Damming that river requires hard choices that nobody is willing to make yet.

Answer (score 3):

Don't flag it because that's just flag spam. However a downvote and close vote would seem to be appropriate. If it takes a while for the closevotes to pile up then that's just how it is.

The question adds nothing to the Q&A repository.

It's closed now, anyway.