# Is ok to answer with an option tree when question is not clear enough

Tags: discussion

I'm aware of you can edit poor questions to make them better, also, depending the case, [answer them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266426/is-it-ok-to-answer-vague-unclear-questions) if you can know what OP is asking even if it's not well phrased, and many more, there are many topics on this.

But today I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39099011/how-can-i-access-a-file-in-a-folder-using-java/39099157#39099157) that without extra info, there are four possible solutions **BUT** from a real good one (IMHO best practice) to an ugly workaround

I thought first in a comment to ask clarification or guide OP, but finally I decided to post an answer like a tree:

---

- You can do it in this way? (Best practice)

  > NO

  - Is a web app?

    > YES

    do this

    > NO

    do this

    > extra problem

    do this ugly and hard-to-maintain workaround

---

I think this is this ok because gives OP (and future users) various options clarifying you **MUST** choose the firsts and IMHO, best one, but maybe is more appropiated to 
ask for clarification and wait?

Comment: Adding multiple possible solutions to an unclear problem in an answeronly makes the question more confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imho that's pretty easy. If the question is unclear, either ask for clarification or flag it as "Unclear what you're asking". That's the best way of dealing with questions like this.

If the question is about a problem that, for example, has four different solutions, each applying to a certain version of the OS, you may want to create a canonical self-Q&A, or a canonical answer if you've found a question that's worth it.

Your answer though, as it is right now, is simply as unclear as the question if not worse (check the comments).

I highly recommend sticking to the usual way of commenting/flagging.

Comment: Deleting answer and waiting for clarification then! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I think it's better to just ask for clarification and wait for a response, or for the OP to edit the required details into the question. Poorly specified questions often attract several incomplete answers (which I see in the low quality queue all the time). Even if the decision tree answer is the top-voted post, everyone who finds that answer in the future has to read through some possible solutions that aren't relevant to them. It's better if the question itself is specific enough to just have one right answer.